# How to randomly spawn objects off-screen close to the player?

Tags: random, game-maker

I am making a zombie game. I want to have it so zombies randomly spawn. My code for this is:

```
instance_create(
  obj_player.x + irandom_range(-300, 300),
  obj_player.y + irandom_range(-300, 300), 
  obj_zom_1 )
```

The problem with this is that zombies will sometimes spawn really close to the player. I want to have it so zombies spawn randomly but to NOT spawn on the visible screen, because seeing zombies materialize out of nowhere looks silly.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the expected limits of your coordinates so I made them constant-like (i.e. screenLeftX). My snippet chooses a random edge of the screen and then a random value between the appropriate coordinate limits of that edge.

```
var positionAlongEdge = 0;
var which = irandom_range(1,4);
if (which == 1) //top edge
{
  positionAlongEdge = irandom_range(screenLeftX, screenRightX);
  instance_create(positionAlongEdge, screenTopY, obj_zom_1);
  //If the shape of zombies causes them to appear on-screen (at the edge),
  //you can push them further beyond the edge:
  //instance_create(positionAlongEdge, screenTopY - 10, obj_zom_1);
  //or
  //instance_create(positionAlongEdge, screenTopY - zombieHeight, obj_zom_1);
}
else if (which == 2) //bottom edge
{
  positionAlongEdge = irandom_range(screenLeftX, screenRightX);
  instance_create(positionAlongEdge, screenBottomY, obj_zom_1);
}
else if (which == 3) //left edge
{
  positionAlongEdge = irandom_range(screenTopY, screenBottomY);
  instance_create(screenLeftX, positionAlongEdge, obj_zom_1);
}
else if (which == 4) //right edge
{
  positionAlongEdge = irandom_range(screenTopY, screenBottomY);
  instance_create(screenRightX, positionAlongEdge, obj_zom_1);
}
```

Comment: Please _explain_ your code and your train of thoughts.

Comment: this is not uniform, you should take into account the size of those areas

Comment: It's giving me an error for the first line: " int where; " it says assignment operator expected. what?

Comment: It still says assignment operator expected for " int positionAlongEdge; " but  the error goes away if I put " = " between them (that messes it up though) so what do I do?

Comment: @DeathSwagga, sorry again; I've never actually used game maker. It seems variables are just `var` typed. You may be forced to initialize it as well. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done more simply:

```
with obj_player //or in the right place in "step"
{
  var xx=random_range(0,room_width);
  var yy=random_range(0,room_height);
  while point_distance(xx,yy,x,y)<300
  {
    var xx=random_range(0,room_width);
    var yy=random_range(0,room_height);
  }
  instance_create(xx, yy, obj_zom_1);
}
```

Comment: This code made the zombies only appear on screen, which is kinda the opposite to what I was aiming to achieve.

Comment: @DeathSwagga, he meant `while distance < 300`. This would try again until the point is **at least** 300 units away, but would still spawn zombies on-screen near the corners.

Comment: @Jon Thank you very much corrected, I mixed up the sign. Yes, I have proposed the code for the "circle" around the player, and not a square.